# Unable to Save or Load Foreign Characters with FireDAC TFDQuery

Tags: sqlite, c++builder, firedac

I have an SQLite database that is configured as:

```
SQLiteFDConnection->Params->Values["StringFormat"]=_D("Unicode");
SQLiteFDConnection->Params->Values["OpenMode"]=_D("CreateUTF8");
```

It has two tables accessed through a `TFDQuery`:

A) `Table1` (`TFDQuery`) has persistent fields and uses a `TDataSource` to show items in a `TDBGrid`.

B) `Table2` (`TFDQuery`) also has persistent fields.

`Table1` works, it shows foreign characters correctly, and the persistent fields are setup to use `TWideStringField`.

`Table2`'s field is also a `TWideStringField` and directly uses the `Table2` to `ExecSQL()` `INSERT INTO` and `UPDATE` statements.  For reading back, it uses `TFDQuery::Open()` then `FieldByName()`.  However, the foreign characters are just question marks.

My question is, since I setup the `StringFormat` to be `Unicode`, why is `Table2` not properly using Unicode?

Updating uses:

```
SQLiteDataModule->Table2->ExecSQL("UPDATE Table2 SET Name=:N where UniqueId=:U",
                 OPENARRAY(Variant, (UnicodeStringVarName, UniqueId)));
```

Reading it back uses `Select * from Table2` in `SQLiteDataModule->Table2->Open()`:

```
String Name=SQLiteDataModule->Table2->FieldByName("Name")->AsString;
```

One problem is I can't output debug information to the Event window and show the correct characters. I wanted to check it just before the `Update` query, but it always shows `?? ??` (there are 4 chars).   The `Name` is used in a `TTreeNode` and I can see foreign characters if I use a normal string, so somewhere between storing and loading it back results with `?? ??`.

String is a `UnicodeString`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say whether the data loss is occurring on the storing or the reading. After executing the `UPDATE` statement, did you check the database directly to make sure the characters were stored correctly to begin with? If so, then when reading back, have you tried using `TField::AsWideString` instead of `TField::AsString`?

Comment: I debugged down to at least the Variant conversion and it was still foreign chars.  I tried the `AsWideString` as well.   In the database looking at it with the `Data Explorer` it just shows `?? ??` but it also does the same when looking at `Table1` where the correct information shows in the `DBGrid`.  So I can't use that to view foreign chars, ugh.

Comment: There are plenty of 3rd party apps for viewing Sqlite databases

Comment: It is in the database wrong - the other table it's in there correctly.  So the `UPDATE` statement is the issue.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you need to provide the field types manually:

```
SQLiteDataModule->Table2->ExecSQL("UPDATE Table2 SET Name=:N where UniqueId=:U",
                 OPENARRAY(Variant, (UnicodeStringVarName, UniqueId)),
                 OPENARRAY(TFieldType, (ftWideString)); // <<<< Field Types
```

Comment: I would have opted to use `Params` instead, eg: `Table2->SQL->Text = "UPDATE Table2 SET Name=:N where UniqueId=:U"; Table2->ParamByName("N")->AsWideString = UnicodeStringVarName; Table2->ParamByName("U")->AsWideString = UniqueId; Table2->ExecSQL();`